# autohotkey's ControlClick,&Set Default not working?

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I'm following [this awesome AutoHotkeyScript](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/68257-toggle-set-default-audio-device-in-windows-7/) and having difficulty getting the `Set Default` button to be clicked.

`off topic:` If you want to replicate, I had to change a few commands for detection of the Sound window to work, so here's where I currently am:

```
   Run mmsys.cpl
   IfWinNotActive,  Sound, , WinActivate,  Sound, 
   WinWait,Sound ; Change "Sound" to the name of the window in your local language
   ControlSend,SysListView321,{Down 1} ; This number selects the matching audio device in the list, change it accordingly
   Sleep, 100
   ControlClick, &Set Default; Change "&Set Default" to the name of the button in your local language
   Sleep, 100
   ;ControlClick,OK
```

now, `the AHK log` shows this as executing:

```
109: {
110: toggle := !toggle
112: if toggle  
114: Run,mmsys.cpl
115: IfWinNotActive,Sound,l
115: WinActivate,Sound (0.03)
116: WinWait,Sound (0.31)
119: ControlSend,SysListView321,{Down 1} (0.01)
120: Sleep,100 (0.11)
121: ControlClick,&Set Default; Change "&Set Default" to the name of the button in your local language
122: Sleep,100 (0.11)
124: }
125: if !toggle  
138: }
139: Return (6.74)
```

but `&Set Default` isn't being clicked.
I've verified that the button name is, in fact, `&Set Default`.
I guess I could use ClassNN's `Button2`, but I'd like to know -why- this isn't working, not just hack my way through it.

Alternatively I can `send [alt down]S[alt up]` to set it as default, but again, that's hacking, and why isn't the simple ControlClick working?

Answer (score 0):

doh, looks like it's a simple syntax problem:

1. you don't need a semicolon at the end of every line
2. [you **do** need a space delimiter between the command and the semicolon.](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Scripts.htm#Comments)

for example, `WinWait, Sound;` is a problem but `WinWait, Sound ;` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For ControlClick:
I finally found my own solution after skimming the documentation more thoroughly:

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm#Reliability

You can specify NA as the sixth parameter to wait for the mouse button to lift.
I found that when firing `Control, Check, ,Button1` prior to `ControlClick` the click didn't work, but adding the `NA` to the end somehow magically fixed it. I suppose a click was being simulated and had not yet lifted.